# Querying CouchBaseLite Views?

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am querying **CouchBaseLite** view but I am getting this exception every time I query it. It is not returning the result.

```
detailMessage: last sequence < 0(-1)
```

View:

```
com.couchbase.lite.View viewItemsByDate = database.getView(String.format("%s/%s", designDocName, byDateViewName));
        viewItemsByDate.setMap(new Mapper() {
            @Override
            public void map(Map<String, Object> document, Emitter emitter) {
                Object createdAt = document.get("text");
                if (createdAt != null) {
                    emitter.emit(createdAt.toString(), null);
                }
            }
        }, "1.0");
```

and My query to this view is:

```
com.couchbase.lite.View view = database.getView(byDateViewName);
        Query query = view.createQuery();//database.createAllDocumentsQuery();

        List<Object> keyArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
        keyArray.add("A");
        keyArray.add("B");
        query.setKeys(keyArray);

        QueryEnumerator rowEnum = query.run();
        for (Iterator<QueryRow> it = rowEnum; it.hasNext();) {
            QueryRow row = it.next();
            Log.d("Document ID:", row.getDocumentId());

        }
```

And I have documents in the database with key `"text": "A"` and `"text": "B"` but still it is showing me exception. `last sequence < 0(-1)`

Why it could not find the rows that I queried for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are querying a different view name than the view name you defined.

Change

```
database.getView(String.format("%s/%s", designDocName, byDateViewName));
```

to

```
database.getView(byDateViewName);
```

and it fixes the problem.

See [Couchbase Lite Android issue #66](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android-core/issues/66#issuecomment-34086386)

Comment: is there anyway we can see the list of defined views?

Comment: There's no public API for that (I don't remember why, honestly), but just look at the names of the views you're registering in your source code.